# Magento 2 Override Shipping Template

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to override:

```
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html
```

I made a copy in:

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/template/shipping.html
```

As explained in http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html

> The order is defined in the /view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml module template. The Blank theme does not override this template. OrangeCo decided they want the product list to be displayed before the Go to Checkout button. To do this, they need to add an overriding template for the corresponding module in the Orange theme folder: app/design/frontend/OrangeCo/orange/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml

I've flushed the cache and static files and it's not overriding. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: did you find out how to fix this? do share if you did i'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

correct path to override would be the following:

```
(magento_dir)/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html
```

delete things under:

```
/var/viewprocessed/
/pub/static/frontend/
```

I am assuming you are on linx here.
go to the console and navigate to `(magento_dir)/bin/`

from within the bin folder, issue the commands in the following order:

```
./magento setup:static-content:deploy
./magento cache:flush
```

it takes some time to deploy the static content. so wait before you flush the cache.

Clean the cache in your web browser and try to view your page that you want to override.

Hope this is clear enough and works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as others. If you followed the above answer and it still did not work, it is likely you have an extension which overrides the template location. Check your custom extensions.